# Gzip decompression adding one extra byte ... Why?

Tags: java, gzip, gzipinputstream, gzipoutputstream

I've written a simple Java code snippet which takes a String, converts it to byte[], and then compresses it using Gzip. Then it decompresses the result to get back the byte[], which now contains one extra garbage value byte. Why is there a garbage value byte here ??

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
String testString = "Sample String here";
byte[] originalBytes = testString.getBytes();

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
gzos.write(originalBytes);
gzos.close();

byte[] compressedBytes = baos.toByteArray();

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressedBytes);
GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(bais);

ByteArrayOutputStream dbaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while(gzis.available() > 0) {
    dbaos.write(gzis.read());
}
byte[] decompressedBytes = dbaos.toByteArray();
String decompressedString = new String(decompressedBytes);

System.out.println(">>" + decompressedString + "<<");
System.out.println("Size of bytes before: " + originalBytes.length);
System.out.println("Size of bytes after: " + decompressedBytes.length);
```

}

Output:

```
>>Sample String here�<<
Size of bytes before: 18
Size of bytes after: 19
```

Can someone tell me why is there a garbage value byte ? How do I get rid of it WITHOUT changing the setup of the code above ??

Answer (score 4):

You are using `available()` here, so you get one extra byte. You should be reading the stream and checking for a value less than `0`. Change this

```
ByteArrayOutputStream dbaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while(gzis.available() > 0) {
    dbaos.write(gzis.read());
}
```

to something like

```
ByteArrayOutputStream dbaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int b;
while ((b = gzis.read()) >= 0) {
    dbaos.write(b);
}
```

and I get

```
>>Sample String here<<
Size of bytes before: 18
Size of bytes after: 18
```

Comment: What if the byte read is a legitimate negative value, which it can be in my actual case (String compression is not what I'm actually doing in my real code) ?

Comment: That is why `read` returns an `int`. This is how you read from a stream until the end. Your way adds an extra byte.

Comment: You mean to say `read` will always return a non-negative integer until it reaches the end ?

Comment: Let's check [`InputStream.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--), it says (in part), *The value byte is returned as an `int` in the range `0` to `255`.* **and** it returns *the next `byte` of data, or `-1` if the end of the stream is reached.*